# How can I manage to view if a table has been read recently in postgresql 12?

Tags: postgresql-12

How can I manage to view if a table has been read recently in postgresql 12 ?

Comment: What's the actual use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the table is only ever accessed via stored procedures or other programmed logic and you have that set to audit access, and measures are taken to stop access by more direct means, then you probably can't.

DBMSs usually don't log read access in a manner that you could query this way, if at all.